# Для чего делать финализированную переменную статической?

Tags: java, переменные, константа, статические-члены

Для чего делать финализированную переменную статической?
В смысле, в каких случаях это имеет смысл и почему нельзя обойтись без этого?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Если коротко - можно обойтись и без этого, но так оптимальнее по памяти в общем случае.

`static final` принадлежит классу, соответственно не зависимо от количества экземпляров этого класса будет создан только один объект типа `static final` переменной.

В случае с просто `final` каждый объект будет содержать ссылку на новую копию.

Если такая переменная содержит ссылку на объект, а не на примитивный тип, значение которого может быть закешировано (intern) - память будет израсходована на хранение одинаковых объектов.

—-

Так же есть различия в жизненном цикле(порядок инициализации).

Статика будет проинициализирована во время загрузки класса класс-лоадером. Т.е. даже если ни один экземпляр этого класса никогда не будет создан.

Просто `final` же напротив - будет проинициализирована в момент создания экземпляра.

---

UPD:

Таким образом получается что для всяких там строк и других immutable объектов, можно ставить `static`, чтобы не плодить идентичные копии, однако для объектов, которые содержат в себе какое-то состояние, которое может быть изменено со временем - уже стоит подумать ставить `static` или нет. Т.е. наличие директивы `final`  еще не говорит о том что объект не поменяется со временем. `final` это атрибут поля, но никак не объекта на который ссылается это поле.